# responsive image with max height of parent

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid

I'm currently creating a website to practice some css. My requirements seem to not get along very well though. I've been trying to solve it all day, but I'm constantly creating new problems by fixing others. 
This is how I'm trying to make it look like inside of the main section:

```
______________________________________
|             |                      | 
|section with |                      |
|fixed size   |  responsive figure   |
|_____________|  (image + caption,   |
|             |  max height =        |
|section with |  combined hight of   |
|fixed size   |  sections)           |
|             |                      |
|_____________|______________________|
```

I need the figcaption to stay **underneath** the image. 
The image has to keep its ratio, using all available space for its width (sticking to left and right edge).
When resizing, I want the figure to stay centered at all times.

The only thing left that is not working yet is setting the maximum height of the image. It's such a simple thing, but somehow I can't get it to work.
The funny thing is, that part even worked fine at some point in the process, but stopped working after adjusting the position of the figure to the center.

Here's my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
  <title>Detailseite zu einem Raum</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="icon" href="Koala.jpg">
  <style>
    main {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
      margin-bottom: 2em;
    }
    
    #figdiv {
      grid-area: 1/2/3/3;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      /* Bild mittig zwischen zwei Rows*/
      max-height: 100%;
    }
    
    figure {
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    img {
      max-width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <header><img id="logo" src="Koala.jpg" alt="Koala Logo" width="65" height="65">Detailseite zu einem Raum</header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="listeVerfuegbareRaeume.html">Verfügbare Räume</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="detailseiteBuchung.html">Detailseite zur Buchung</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="raumBuchen.html">Raumbuchung anlegen</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <main>
    <section>
      <h4>Informationen zum Raum</h4>
      <div>
        <!-- Ursprünglich: id="raumInfo" -->
        <ul id="raumInfoListe">
          <li>Nummer: A.E.01</li>
          <li>Bezeichnung: Hörsaal</li>
          <li>Gebäude: EF42</li>
          <li>Kapazität: XY</li>
          <li>Ausstattungsmerkmale:
            <ul>
              <li>1 Beamer</li>
              <li>2 Whiteboards</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- <figure> semantische Auszeichnung der Abbildung
                    <img src="Office.jpg" alt="Foto des Raumes">
                    <figcaption>Abbildung: Foto des Raumes</figcaption>
                </figure> -->
      </div>
    </section>
    <section id="tabellenContainer">
      <h4>Tabelle der Buchungen zum Raum</h4>
      <table id="tabelleRaumBuchungen">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Datum</th>
            <th>Zeitraum</th>
            <th>Bezeichnung</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>12.10.2018</td>
            <td>12:00-20:00 Uhr</td>
            <td><a href="detailseiteBuchung.html">Kolloquium</a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>13.10.2018</td>
            <td>14:00-20:00 Uhr</td>
            <td><a href="detailseiteBuchung.html">Kolloquium</a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>14.10.2018</td>
            <td>15:00-20:00 Uhr</td>
            <td><a href="detailseiteBuchung.html">Kolloquium</a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </section>
    <div id="figdiv">
      <figure>
        <img src="Office.jpg" alt="Foto des Raumes">
        <figcaption>Abbildung: Foto des Raumes</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
  </main>
  <aside>
    <label>Aktuelle Meldungen:</label>
    <ul>
      <li>11.10.2018, eine aktuelle Meldung</li>
      <li>12.10.2018, noch eine aktuelle Meldung</li>
    </ul>
  </aside>
  <footer>
    <label>© Copyright 2018</label>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

What I did here can probably be simplified, feel free to let me know about that as well :D

(And I'm using Google Chrome btw)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add three sections to a div element and fix the height as you need it to be and then set the fixed sized sections in the div under the parent div and add the image div too to the div under the parent div and define styling definitions in terms of percentages for responsive design.

[image for understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLC5R.png)

Comment: Is it also possible without setting a specific size to the sections? Currently, the height of the sections is set automatically and its pretty much perfect, but it gets stretched when I extend the window to the point where the image height gets higher than the height of the fixed sections.

Comment: You have to set the image's height in percentage, it will take care of sizing the image with respect to the div holding this image

Comment: yes, I agree. But I wouldn't like to hard code the size of the div. The div should simply be as small as possible to make the content of the sections fit. So the height can vary, depending on the browser / device you're using.

Comment: Using maxwidth function in your styling sheet you can control the height with respect to different layouts, it is always the height is hardcoded in most of the websites and width is captured from the screen, as there can a huge page meaning site can long in height, if not given the image will go with its default height, which might spoil the look when viewed from different devices. this site might help you: https://www.websitedimensions.com/